# Sorting table columns and displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, struts2

I am creating a dynamic table manager using JSP struts 2 and backend is plain oracle DB.

All this is done.
If I set a page limit of say 10 then on change of page only the next 10 set of rows is fetched and displayed. So basically at any point of time i will have only 10 rows in my page.
Now I want to add sorting by column functionality to this table manager,it will be similar to an excel sheet where we can sort in ascending or descending order columnwise.

How do I do this ?

What I thought was everytime a column is clicked I will go to the action and fetch the rows in ascending or descending order.

Is this the optimal way or is there any other optimal solution?

Comment: use display tag lib , it has inherent sorting functionality

Answer (score 0):

You get all your data in the form of JSON object and create your table using javascript (you can also provide pagination - with logic). Make a function in javascript which creates the table. Now whenever sorting is done (asc or desc) sort your JSON Object on that particular column. Then again call your 'create table' function in javascript. This will prevent making server-side call or database call. The processing will be done at your client side which will boost your performance.
TIP: Get all the table data at one go and pass it to the front-end

**Updated:**
Sort your json object  Sorting object based on 'name' attribute
`var sortedArray = myArray.sort(function(a,b){

                                   if (a.name < b.name)

                                      return -1;

                                   else if (a.name == b.name)

                                      return 0;

                                   else

                                      return 1;

                               });`

Comment: I am not using JSON.I am just retrieveing data in a hashmap and displaying it using struts 2 tag.So basically all my data is in a Hashmap.

Answer (score 0):

Following are the multiple approaches you can take

1. Sorting the data in DB using order by and displaying the results.
   For this you can use display tags already available for struts like [DISPLAYTAG](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=http://www.displaytag.org/&ei=1aITUfzfB8GUrges5YHICA&usg=AFQjCNHAJci2y_XPZ_JQtH-aWqe-Xa9Bvg&sig2=L6S2XsNRbunl2LD4pyodUQ&bvm=bv.42080656,d.bmk&cad=rja)

2 . Sorting the table on the HTML page using JavaScript libraries like Jquery example [TableSorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)

3.Fetch the data once from the Db and store it in session and sort it using java.util.Comparator : Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712031/how-to-sort-database-results-not-populated-to-a-standard-result-table-in-a-jsp-p/14750874#14750874#answer-14750874)

Answer (score 0):

If your using only tables then check the below link. It is Jquery data table plugin.It provides pagination, seleting max number of rows per page and column sorting.

http://www.datatables.net/examples/

Answer (score -1):

ok, you have two options, either use your own logic for paging
or try to use **struts2-jquery-grid-plugins**.

this link is the full documentation for how to use grid in your application

http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/GridTag

and this is the working demo of struts2-grid-plugin

http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase/index.action

as well as you can download war file or source code of this here
    http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/downloads/list 
  find **struts2-jquery-mobile-showcase-3.5.1.war**